# how can i update this array in MongoDB?

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, mongodb

hi guys i'm using mongodb with python for storing some information but i want to delete the **2nd object** in the **timed array** in the **1st ID** object without touching the second id object. Do you know how can i do?

[image: There is the database look]

I have already tried with some code but nothing.

Comment: Please share what you tried, also which libraries you are using.

Comment: Please don't paste images. Use formatted text instead.

Comment: sorry fot the pic btw the library si pymongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `$unset` and `$pull` to remove that array element.

Something like this works:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import pprint

client = MongoClient()
db = client['test']
collection = db.sotest1

a = list(collection.find({'_id': ObjectId('5e6d9cb1e61607439cf2416f')}))
print('Before Update')
pprint.pprint(a)

#  Remove by Index using unset and pull
collection.update_one({'_id': ObjectId('5e6d9cb1e61607439cf2416f')},
                      {'$unset': {'timed.576819964179382272.timed.1': 1}})
collection.update_one({'_id': ObjectId('5e6d9cb1e61607439cf2416f')},
                      {'$pull': {'timed.576819964179382272.timed': None}})

a = list(collection.find({'_id': ObjectId('5e6d9cb1e61607439cf2416f')}))
print('After update')
pprint.pprint(a)
```

Results:

```
Before Update
[{'_id': ObjectId('5e6d9cb1e61607439cf2416f'),
  'timed': {'173569203977060353': {'name': 'Pollig#4963',
                                   'timed': [{'strObj': 'stuff in here'}]},
            '576819964179382272': {'name': 'Ranka#9895',
                                   'timed': [{'str1': 'test'},
                                             {'str1': 'remove me'},
                                             {'str2': 'test3'},
                                             {'extra': 'extra object in '
                                                       'array'}]}}}]
After update
[{'_id': ObjectId('5e6d9cb1e61607439cf2416f'),
  'timed': {'173569203977060353': {'name': 'Pollig#4963',
                                   'timed': [{'strObj': 'stuff in here'}]},
            '576819964179382272': {'name': 'Ranka#9895',
                                   'timed': [{'str1': 'test'},
                                             {'str2': 'test3'},
                                             {'extra': 'extra object in '
                                                       'array'}]}}}]
```